# How do you put raw-sql projections in an object using Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, projection

Let's say I have a query that begins with the following projections:

```
SELECT t.term as term, count(g.id) as amount
```

This is raw sql, and I am using createSqlQuery on the Hibernate session object. What I'd like to do is take these projections and put them in an object that has a "term" and "amount" properties.

With HQL, we can use "select new ClassName(...)", but this doesn't work with a raw SQL query.

How do we do it? I get back a bunch of [LObject's... and I have no idea what to do with them. If I can get Hibernate to put them into some kind of non-entity value object, that'd be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I can get Hibernate to put them into some kind of non-entity value object, that'd be great.

You can tell Hibernate to return non-managed value objects from a native SQL query by applying a *"result transformer"*. From the reference documentation:

> #### [16.1.5. Returning non-managed entities](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13904)
>
> It is possible to apply a
>   ResultTransformer to native SQL
>   queries, allowing it to return
>   non-managed entities.
>
> ```
> sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT NAME, BIRTHDATE FROM CATS")
>         .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CatDTO.class))
> ```
>
> This query specified:
>
> - the SQL query string
> - a result transformer
>
> The above query will return a list of
>   `CatDTO` which has been instantiated
>   and injected the values of `NAME` and
>   `BIRTHNAME` into its corresponding
>   properties or fields.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13696

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, NAME, BIRTHDATE, DOG_ID FROM CATS").addEntity(Cat.class)
```

Assuming your object with the term and amount properties has only those 2 object attributes a similar query with *your* raw SQL should return a list of those objects which you can then iterate through one by one.